# I have a AWS cognito JWT token which has custom claim role.How to secure my APIs using springboot based on the roles at backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-security, amazon-cognito, jwt

I have an application where I get JWT token after login from the cognito pool.The JWt token has user claims.It has a custom claim called ROle.Based on role I want to secure my APIS.For example If I have a user he needs to access only /user APIS and admin needs to access all the APIS.I am using Springboot at backend.So How to secure using Spring Security

Answer (score 0):

since already Coignito is integrated, using API gateway and Cognito user pool authentication, every API can be authenticated and authorised. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html

Comment: Is there a way to authorize using SpringSecurity?

Comment: Yes, there is an option to integrate custom Lambda authorizer into API gateway. You can use any custom authorizer.

Answer (score 0):

I had exact the same issue. As default Spring Resource Server (using Spring Security) read the claim `scope` add create a list of granted authorities. It adds the prefix `SCOPE_` so the authority might look like this: `SCOPE_{authority}`. Since you might use other claim in the JWT token provided by Cognito, you have to convert it into Granted Authorities. So Spring is available to check it. Let's check out my Github repository to see how I convert values of claim `cognito:groups` into authorities, so that Spring Security can check it. You can do the same with other claims.

Repo: https://github.com/quan-nguyen97/springboot-cognito-auth

See this documentation as well: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization

Comment: you might find [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) helpful to find [simpler solutions](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/webmvc-jwt-default) and also a [better pattern](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) than having the web or mobile frontend handle tokens

Answer (score 0):

All of [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) are configured with Cognito. It covers many use cases: resource server with a JWT decoder as you seem to be looking for, but also resource server with token introspection and OAuth2 clients.

It is declined for servlets or reactive applications, as well as with or without Spring Boot Starters of mine (which make it possible to configure authorities mapping from application properties).

Sample for a servlet resource server with JWT decoder:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity()
public class SecurityConfig {
}
```

```yaml
cognito-issuer: https://cognito-idp...
allowed-origins:
- http://localhost:4200
- http://localhost:3000

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      security:
        cors:
        - path: /**
          allowed-origins: ${allowed-origins}
        issuers:
        - location: ${cognito-issuer}
          username-claim: username
          authorities:
          - path: $.cognito:groups
        permit-all:
        - "/actuator/health/readiness"
        - "/actuator/health/liveness"
```

This will map authorities from a single `cognito:groups` claim, without any prefix nor case transformation, but, with just properties, you might add as many claims as you like (thanks to JSON-Path, even those that are not just under root node), and for each:

- add a prefix
- transform to upper or lower case